# selenium IDE is successfully sending keys to hidden input box, but webdriver is throwing an error as element not visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an input box which is not visible, Selenium IDE in record and playback mode is able to send keys into it and out put is successful. 
same thing webdriver is throwing an error element is not visible therefore cannot be interacted with.
I have tried scripting using document.findElements.ByclassName.. there is no error but there is no output as well.
pls see the code below:

```
{
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.cwd-clue")).click();
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//input[@class='cwd_input']")));
    System.out.println("assert true");
    WebElement tmpElement= driver.findElement(By.className("cwd_input"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cwd_input')    [0].click();",tmpElement);
    tmpElement.sendKeys("TELLER");}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add WebDriverWait as shown.

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='cwd_input']");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(ele));
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the info, getting error as " The method presenceOfElementLocated(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)"

Comment: changed to :driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.cwd-clue")).click();
    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='cwd_input']"));
    WebDriverWait wait=(WebDriverWait) new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) ele));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cwd_input')[0].click();",ele);
    ele.sendKeys("TELLER"); getting error as RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.....

Comment: Bad that u are still getting error. I want to know why Javascript executor is required. and if the xpath is correct.

Comment: just checked the wait object is never used. why do you think so, may be thats the reason, how can i make it work